# training/validation/test sets in python for regression

Tags: regression, cross-validation

I want to split my data in 3 partitions training, validation and test: 70% training, 15% validation and 15% test for regression. Python provides a way to do that only for training and testing by `cross_validation.train_test_split`. Any Ideas?

Comment: This question is old but still, you could use this helpful [post1](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15135/train-test-validation-set-splitting-in-sklearn), [post2](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/67489/how-to-split-data-into-3-parts-in-python-training70-validation15-and-te) and [post3](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/52632/cross-validation-vs-train-validate-test).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cross_validation.train_test_split`, 2 times.

First with `(70,30) => (training, validation_test)` and secondly use `(50,50) -> (validation,test)`.